# How to get default theme data parameters in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, the `CardTheme`. I know you can retrieve it this way:

`Theme.of(context).cardTheme`

However, how can I get its default parameters? I tried looking in the .dart files but it's difficult to find them.
What I would like to do is find default values for any given Widget in Flutter, so I can do something like this in the instance of a Card:

```
shape: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.copyWith(
                          clipBehavior: default,
                          color: default,
                          elevation: default + 25,    // For example.
                          margin: default,
                          shadowColor: default,
                          shape: default,
                          surfaceTintColor: default,
                        ),
```

I would find it useful as I often do not touch certain parameters, and when I find myself wanting to work starting from the defaults as a reference, I don't know where to get them.

Comment: Did you try Theme.of(context).cardTheme.elevation ?

Comment: @AndréVicente No I did not... Did not think to use the dot operator further, now I can set everything to its defaults. Please submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost done it, you can get the default value this way `Theme.of(context).cardTheme.elevation`. So, to add 25 to elevation you just need to use like this:

```
var elevation = Theme.of(context).cardTheme.elevation;

shape: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.copyWith(
                      elevation: elevation + 25,
                    ),
```